# Split data for equal group (PL/SQL, SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, bulk

I have number of id's:

```
Select count(*) Into count_id From table_I;--4
```

I know that I have total `total_user = 109` (number of records). So I want to split it to equal group:

```
Select round(count(*)/count_user,0) Into mapUser From table_U;
```

So I have `4 group`. In the `first three will be 27` and `last should be 28` users.

Now I want to `for each group` assign the unique ID.

```
set serveroutput on 
declare 
      CURSOR cur IS Select * From table_U FOR UPDATE OF USER_ID;
      mapUser NUMBER;
      l_rec table_U%rowtype;
      x_mapUser Number := 0;--number between 0-27
      c_obj_id NUMBER := 1;
      count_id NUMBER := 0;

      type T1 is table of number(10) index by binary_integer;
      V1 T1;    

begin
     Select count(*) Into count_id From table_I;--count_id = 4
     Select round(count(*)/count_id,0) Into mapUser From table_U; --mapUser = 27

     SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO V1 FROM table_I;--it's 4 id (id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4)

    OPEN cur;
        LOOP FETCH cur INTO l_rec;
         EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;

           IF x_mapUser > mapUser Then --0-27 > 27
                x_mapUser := 1;                   
                c_obj_id := c_obj_id +1;--next value from V1
           End if;

          UPDATE table_U SET USER_ID = V1(c_obj_id) WHERE CURRENT OF cur;

         x_mapUser := x_mapUser +1;

        END LOOP;
       CLOSE cur;        
end;
```

But I don't know how to change my `IF` and last value from `cur` assign as well `id_4`. I'm doing something wrong here :/

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something which worked for me:

```
merge into table_u a
using (select rd, i.id
         from (select u.rowid rd, cnt - mod(rownum-1, cnt) rn 
                 from table_u u, (select count(1) cnt from table_i) ) u
         join (select row_number() over( order by id) rn, id from table_i) i using (rn)) b
on (a.rowid = b.rd)         
when matched then update set a.user_id = b.id
```

My test tables:

```
create table table_i as (
  select level*10 id from dual connect by level <= 4);

create table table_u as (
  select cast(null as number(3)) user_id, level id from dual connect by level <= 109);
```

The highest value from second table was assigned 28 times, others 27 times. It's because I used

```
cnt - mod(rownum-1, cnt) rn
```

to count joining column. I don't know if it is important for you though. :) The base of this solution is `mod()` which allows us to cycle between `1` and `cnt` (in this case 4).

You can do it in PLSQL as you showed, but SQL solutions are typically faster and preferred when possible.

Comment: Ponder - I have just tested your code and on my site is working, great, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`ntile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm):

```
select u.*, ntile(4) over (order by user_id) as grp
from table_u u;
```

I don't know what ordering, if any, you want.  You can use a random number if you like.

If you want to enumerate the values in each group, use a subquery:

```
select u.*, row_number() over (partition by grp order by grp) as seqnum
from (select u.*, ntile(4) over (order by user_id) as grp
      from table_u u
     ) u;
```

Comment: ok, and now how to update column (col1) from table_u ? like for group_ 1 has id_1, group_ 2 has id_2 .....(id from table_I)

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake and did it with my PL/SQL code as well:

```
...
x_mapUser Number := 0
...
OPEN cur;
 LOOP FETCH cur INTO l_rec;
  EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;
     UPDATE table_U SET USER_ID = V1(c_obj_id) WHERE CURRENT OF cur;

     IF x_mapUser > mapUser-1 AND c_obj_id < count_id Then
            x_mapUser := 0;
            c_obj_id := c_obj_id +1;
     End if;

 x_mapUser := x_mapUser +1;

 END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
```